# Youtube API Bad Request 400

Tags: .net, api, youtube, bad-request

Hopefully someone has some experience in this area as have run out of avenues to work out whats going on.

My question is why am i getting a bad request 400 error when trying to upload a video to youtube via the api. I'm using the .net library and can successfully upload locally but not remotely on my hosting at discountasp. The following is the error message i receive but as you can tell it doesn't hold much information

> The remote server returned an error:
>   (400) Bad Request.
>
> [WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   +6038435    Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
>   +85
>
> [GDataRequestException: Execution of
>   request failed:
>   http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads]
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
>   +228    Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32
>   retryCounter) +487
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32
>   retryCounter) +523
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32
>   retryCounter) +523
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32
>   retryCounter) +523
>   Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
>   +10    Google.GData.Client.MediaService.EntrySend(Uri
>   feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry,
>   GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData
>   data) +541
>   Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri
>   feedUri, AtomEntry newEntry,
>   AsyncSendData data) +88
>   Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri
>   feedUri, TEntry entry) +58
>   Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeService.Upload(String
>   userName, YouTubeEntry entry) +98

Comment: I suggest you use Fiddler (http://www.fiddlertool.com/) to see what exactly your client is sending to the server, and what exactly is the response. If it doesn't help, paste it here.

Comment: So the fact i can upload locally but not remotely not say anything about this?

Comment: Not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: It turns out i'm sending a mime type of application/unknown as the video type i'm submitting which youtube doesn't like. That one took a while to work out.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code or the requests that are being sent this cannot be answered, but the first thing I would check is:

a) The request structure - correct format, arguments, path

b) Encoding of the parameters you are passing: these I imagine should be URL encoded. E.g if your parameter includes a "/" then the service with interpret this as a path delimiter.